# Struts not validating email in form input

Tags: java, forms, validation, struts

I have an HTML form, I'm trying to use Struts to validate that the user has entered a valid email address before registering on the site.

When the form is submitted, no validation appears to occur and the form is just submitted as-is to the action parameter class.

I'm new to Struts, so please assume I've missed the obvious (because I probably have).

My form looks like this (UserRegistrationAddForm.jsp):

```
<form name="registrationAddForm" method="post" action="UserRegistrationAdd">
    <div class="form-label-holder">
        <label for="email"><fmt:message key="LOGON_ID" bundle="${storeText}" /><span class="mandatoryindicator"> *</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-field-holder">
        <input id="email" class="required email" type="text" name="logonId" value="<c:out value="${paramSource.logonId}" />" />
    </div>
    <input type="image" src="<c:out value="${jspStoreImgDir}" />mobile/images/next-button.png" />
</form>
```

My configuration is (struts-config.xml):

```
<struts-config>
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="UserRegAddForm"
            type="org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorForm">
            <form-property name="logonId" type="java.lang.String" />
        </form-bean>
    </form-beans>
    <action
        parameter="com.example.UserRegistrationAddCmd"
        path="/UserRegistrationAdd" type="com.example.LTPATokenGenerationEnabledBaseAction"
        name="UserRegAddForm">
        <set-property property="https" value="0:1"/>
        <set-property property="authenticate" value="0:0"/>
    </action>
    <plug-in className="org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn">
        <set-property property="pathnames" value="/WEB-INF/validator-rules.xml"/>
    </plug-in>
</struts-config>
```

With the validation configured as (validator-rules.xml):

```
<form-validation>
    <form name="UserRegAddForm">
        <field property="logonId" depends="required,email">
            <arg key="registrationAddForm.logonId" />
        </field>
    </form>
</form-validation>
```

The stack shows:

```
at com.example.BaseAction.executeAction(BaseAction.java:722)
    at com.example.struts.BaseAction.execute(BaseAction.java:150)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at com.example.struts.ECActionServlet.processRequest(ECActionServlet.java:218)
    at com.example.struts.ECActionServlet.doPost(ECActionServlet.java:174)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
```

The stack trace is from an error at the next step in processing, so it should never have got that far.

Interestingly the stack doesn't mention any reference to my action type `com.example.LTPATokenGenerationEnabledBaseAction` so I'm assuming I've mis-configured something?

Comment: are you using the default stack?

Comment: Default stack for what, sorry?

Comment: usually on your struts.xml, you define a namespace, you have to define what stack it is using. is this even struts2? or struts1?

Comment: What version are you using? Struts 1?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but maybe you should be using org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorActionForm in your form-bean tag.

Comment: It's declared as the type attribute in the form-bean tag. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Mikaveli, yes
<form-bean name="UserRegAddForm"
            type="org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorActionForm">

Comment: Yes, I've done that (my struts-config.xml is in the question above).